# PHP - Skip object of class null

Tags: php, arrays, class, symfony-3.4

I am pulling  data from my database on specific entity and form other tables related to them.

How can I skip an error when some object is null in db?

Error is:

> **Call to a member function getName() on null**

Code:

```
$results = $this->getMyRepository()->findAll();

    $rows = [];

    $rows[] = array(
        "id",
        "user",
        "category"
    );

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $rows[] = [
            $row->getId(),
            $row->getUser()->getFullName(),
            $row->getCategory()->getName(),
        ];
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if the variable is null before working with it

```
 foreach ($results as $row) {
      $rows[] = [
        $row->getId(),
        $row->getUser()->getFullName(),
        !is_null($row->getCategory()->getName()) ? $row->getCategory()->getName() : '',
      ];
   }
```

Documentation: [is_null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

Comment: This won't skip the exception if `getCategory` gives you `null`. This still invokes `getName` on it. This could work but is_null should check the category, not the name - `!is_null($row->getCategory()) ? $row->getCategory()->getName() : ''`.

Comment: How to pass $row->getCreated(new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'), because "format" can not be called on null? @Haru

Comment: Again, ternary operator, or null-collation. For example `($row->getCreated() ?? new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d')`.

Comment: Show us what exactly you're doing. What error do you get?

Comment: I tried your example and got "Call to a member function format() on null" @Haru

Comment: Please make sure you put brackets correctly. It works, see this snippet - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38bdf99a2d050a95251d47e842bb447780b886c2

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, but exception. Errors [might be suppressed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) by "@" operator.

You can't *just* skip exception. To handle them you need to use try-catch block.

Perhaps you want to check if user and category exists. Your code might look like this below (using ternary operator).

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $rows[] = [
        $row->getId(),
        ($user = $row->getUser()) ? $user->getFullName() : null,
        ($category = $row->getCategory()) ? $category->getName() : null,
    ];
}
```